# Wix Installer Error 2343 on simple project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, windows-installer

I have Product.wxs in my Visual Studo 2013:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?define ProductName="Soft" ?>
  <?define ProductVersion="1.0.0.0" ?>
  <?define ProductCode="*" ?>
  <?define UpgradeCode="49996E7A-4717-4577-BA6A-3501BBDFF1A0" ?>
  <?define Manufacturer="Soft LLC" ?>

    <Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductName)" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" ></Property>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Overridable="yes" Value="License.rtf"/>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductName)"/>
      </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File Id='SoftEXE' DiskId='1' Source='C:\Projects\Soft Installer\Browser\soft.exe'/>
      </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

I added WixUIExtension.

I builded installer and ran it. But after License agreement dialog I have Error 2343.

My sistem and soft:

- Windows Server 2012 R2

  Visual Studio 2013 Community 2013

  Wix Toolset 3.9.1208

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Here is the requested log information. It is big so I attached a link.

[WIX Installer Error Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7myrqfkxtcfwmj5/Soft%20Installer%20Log.txt?dl=0)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `"WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION"` needs to be `INSTALLFOLDER`, that should fix it.

```
    ...
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER"></Property>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I would take a look at http://iswix.codeplex.com/ ...  This FOSS project that I maintain has advanced project templates that serve as scaffolding and graphical designers to do most of the heavy lifting.  It includes the MajorUpgrade, UI and other experiences as default when it creates your project so that you don't have to waste your time trying to get it to work.  Then later you can go back to read and understand it in greater detail.